Find the threshold that returns the highest precision
I have this dataset:
(26.5625,0)
(29.5625,0)
(30.390625,0)
(18.640625,0)
(27.984375,0)
(26.984375,0)
(25.703125,0)
(25.78125,0)
(32.09375,0)
(25.59375,0)
(27.703125,0)
(30.828125,0)
(23.578125,0)
(21.890625,0)
(25.734375,0)
(24.65625,0)
(27.46875,0)
(31.640625,0)
(26.53125,0)
(25.078125,0)
(30.65625,0)
(24.515625,0)
(25.21875,0)
(21.78125,0)
(28.984375,0)
(29.765625,0)
(27.171875,1)
(30.46875,1)
(35.3125,1)
(27.90625,1)
(34.9375,1)
(33.4375,1)
(30.90625,1)
(31.671875,1)
(32.40625,1)
(26.078125,1)
(31.171875,1)
(36.21875,1)
(35.0625,1)
(35.65625,1)
(36.65625,1)
(37.96875,1)
(31.953125,1)
(33.15625,1)
(37.34375,1)

And the ordering with the corresponding precision is:
ordered_labels: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

average precision: 0.7338

I'm trying to find the threshold (for example 27.0) which returns the highest precision (0.7338 in that case), which means as many as possible the '1' are on the left, and as low as possible the '0' on the right. (For example: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] has a precision of 1.0) I've tried logistic regression but I'm getting back threshold as '0.7' instead of a number such as 27.0.
Should I use linear regression or svm for that dataset?
My outputs: (code below)
Precision: [0.33333333 0.         0.         1.        ]
Recall: [1. 0. 0. 0.]
Threshold: [0.13154558 0.7006058  0.72969373]

This is the code I am using:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from ast import literal_eval

# Create a simple dataset
scores_labels_path = 'data.txt'
X, y = [], []
with open(scores_labels_path) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = literal_eval(line.rstrip())
        X.append(line[0])
        y.append(line[1])

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(y)
# X1, y1 = make_classification(n_samples=1000, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=7)
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_scores = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_scores[:, 1])

print("Precision: {}".format(precision))
print("Recall: {}".format(recall))
print("Threshold: {}".format(threshold))


The issue is that you're using a logistic regression model, a probabilistic model. The threshold you're getting is not on your input feature, but the probability output by the logistic regression model.
Do it without machine learning models:

Sort the data by feature values.
For each unique value, calculate the precision of classifying all points with a feature value <= to the current value as class 0 and all points with a feature value > current value as class 1.
The feature value that gives the highest precision is your threshold.

Implementation:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, names=['feature', 'label'])
data = data.sort_values('feature')
precisions= []
threshold = data['feature'].unique()
for threshold in thresholds:
    predicted_labels = np.where(data['feature'] <= threshold, 0, 1)
    tp = np.sum((predicted_labels == 1) & (data['label'] == 1))
    fp = np.sum((predicted_labels == 1) & (data['label'] == 0))
    precision = tp / (tp + fp) 
    precisions.append(precision)
max_precision_index = np.argmax(precisions)
best_threshold = thresholds[max_precision_index]
print("Best threshold: {}".format(best_threshold))

